# Enabling Compiz Disables Windows Title Bar - Why?

Tags: compiz, titlebar

Ubuntu 11.04 here.

I have Compiz Fusion Icon. When I choose compiz, to benefit from the effects, my windows title bar disappear.

How can I make it appear, and preserve the effects ?

Note:

If I go to *Compiz Fusion Icon > Select Windows Manager > Metacity*
**I got the tittle bar but not the effects.**

If I go to *Compiz Fusion Icon > Select Windows Manager > Compiz*
**I got the effects but not the title bar.**

Thanks

Comment: I had similar problem here. Eventually it went right.

Comment: @Chethan - me too. Before doing this upgrade (that as make me reconfigure a lot of things) I had it working. But I never knew why. Because I never knew why, I knew that, if it happen again, I will not know what to do. And there's exactly were I am. :) I hope someone could explain this properly so that this don't happen again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to:

```
CompizConfig Settings Manager > Effects
```

Make SURE **Window Decoration** is **checked**.

Comment: I might have needed also gtk-window-decorator --replace command, both with a pc logut and restart