# Title bar disappears suddenly when Compiz is enabled

Tags: 11.10, compiz, lubuntu, lxde, titlebar

I am running Lubuntu 11.10 (LXDE based on Ubuntu 11.10). A few days ago, I installed the Macbuntu, but it isn't compatible with LXDE and so, I uninstalled it. And today I installed Compiz (I have tried to install Compiz in Lubuntu 11.10 before and everything goes well at that time). I tried to run Compiz with the command `compiz --replace` and everything seems ok. But after a short time (usually within three minutes), the title bar and taskbar disappeared suddenly, and I cannot open any program with the hot key (e.g. I usually open the terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T`, but it doesn't work at that time).

I can do nothing but kill the `Xorg` and stop the Compiz in tty1. Now the system is fine without Compiz. But when I try to run Compiz, the horrible thing will happen again. and I noticed that, usually when I close a window, or change the configuration of Compiz, the title bar would disappear suddenly. I really don't know how I can fix it. Can anyone give a hand to me?

Another: i have run `gtk-window-decorator --replace` to start the window decoration, i got the error:

```
Failed to load theme "Ambiance": Failed to find a valid file for theme Ambiance


(gtk-window-decorator:3994): Wnck-WARNING **: Unhandled action type _OB_WM_ACTION_UNDECORATE
```

Comment: I have that problem too but when I press Ctrl+Alt+Del and log out and then log back in, everything goes right. The title bar disappears only when I change my desktops. How many desktops do you have in Compiz general settings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling Compiz Disables Windows Title Bar - Why?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38078/enabling-compiz-disables-windows-title-bar-why)

Comment: i have looked through the question you referred to. but nothing help. @jokerdino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it has some connection with some animation adds-on, such as `beam`, when open those special effects, compiz will crash. though i didnt know why

Comment: Try emerald it may help you

Comment: thx, i have installed it. now everything goes fine without such crash animation(e.g. beam .etc), just leave it at that :)

Comment: @MarkZar - please add what you have done as an answer and accept it by clicking that tick button so that the question can be closed.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run compiz setting manager than(you can run it from terminal typing `ccsm`).
Than enable than disable `Windows Decoration` than restart your computer.

Comment: I might have needed also along 'gtk-window-decorator --replace' command, and a successful restart and logout prior are also very necessary as you mention

Answer (score 2):

I faced title-bar-disappear issue on Ubuntu 14.04. I resolved it by restarting the unity service.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: doesnt work for me on ubuntu 20

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to fix this was to get in the compiz setings manager and put put to default all the options for the Windows Decoration, the command line got updated. I then rebooted and it seems to have fixed the issue.

The symtoms for me were: Windows Decoration dispparearing every time I did a minimize and restore.

I'm running Ubuntu though, I don't know if that'll fix your case.  I had a similar issue in the pass which running "gtk-window-decorator --replace"  at start up fixed.