# No window borders after switching to Compiz in Lubuntu

Tags: compiz, lubuntu, window-manager, openbox

I have Lubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. I just installed compiz and ran `compiz --replace` to switch from openbox to compiz.

It's mostly working but there are no windows borders. Window decoration is enabled but that's not helping.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

You can install **CompizConfig Settings Manager** from Software Center and then:

1. Run CompizConfig Settings Manager
2. Type **decoration** in the **Filter** text box.

   [image]
3. Activate **Window Decoration** by clicking on the check box.
4. You can click on the <kbd>Window Decoration</kbd> button for more configurations.

Comment: I have already checked the decorater. Still no change !

Comment: See these links carefully: ** http://askubuntu.com/questions/104690/title-bar-disappears-suddenly-when-compiz-is-enabled ** http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/463596-compiz-doesnt-work-lxde-2.html  **  http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-mint-84/linux-mint-10-lxde-i-dont-know-how-to-start-compiz-fusion-884013/

Answer (score 0):

try compiz --ccp  instead. ;-)